# Expanding selector without using CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

In my HTML I have a table that basically goes:

| 1 | $3.00 |

| 2 | $5.00 |

| 3 | $1.00 |

And you can switch back and forth between which is highlighted by clicking on the number value. The code behind in Angular uses event.target as Element to get the number. I want to be able to also click on the amount field, but the only solution I can think of is to make the CSS of the number field overlap above the amount field... which I know is a terrible idea. In the Angular functionality I cannot figure out a way to assign a index number to the specific field when it is clicked on. How do I make it so I can click on '$3.00' and get the number #1?

HTML:

```
<td>
        <tr id='{{ code }}' *ngFor="let code of this.codeArr" (click)="specificCheckDetails($event)">{{ code }}</tr>
    </td>

    <td>
        <tr id="{{ item }}" *ngFor="let item of this.itemArr">${{ item }}</tr>
    </td>
```

Comment: Is your table generated using an *ngFor loop, based on an array in your TS code?

Comment: can you show your code? Kindly paste it here in your question? With looping you get the index and you can easily check it if its via `*ngFor`. Kindly share your code.

Comment: Added code and fixed a field... it's not using the index value, it's a seperate array. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

If it's list using `*ngFor` you can do sth like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <div class="item" (click)="executeAction(item, i)">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```